# Switch statement inside of main, but is not outputting and instead skipping straight to printing the tic tac toe board

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm working on a school project and cannot fathom why the switch statement is not printing in main. I am trying to make a menu selection and I have used the same code in another project and it works flawlessly.

```
char square[] = { 'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

int choices, def;
int checkWin();

struct Player
{
    char init[3]; //initials for player
    char xo; //x or o
    int wins; //player wins
    int losses; //player losses
    int ties; //player ties
    int turn; //players turn
};

int checkWin()
{
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])
        return 1;

    else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])
        return 1;

    else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])
        return 1;

    else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])
        return 1;

    else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])
        return 1;

    else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])
        return 1;

    else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9]) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])
        return 1;

    else if (square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3' &&
             square[4] != '4' && square[5] != '5' && square[6] != '6' &&
             square[7] != '7' && square[8] != '8' && square[9] != '9')
        return 0;

    else {
        return  - 1;
    }
}

void displayBoard()
{
    printf("\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n");

    printf("Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)\n\n\n");
    //board display
    printf("     |     |     \n");
    printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[1], square[2], square[3]);
    printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
    printf("     |     |     \n");
    printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[4], square[5], square[6]);
    printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
    printf("     |     |     \n");
    printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[7], square[8], square[9]);
    printf("     |     |     \n\n");
}

int main() {
    int player = 1, i, choice;
    char mark;

    switch(choices) {

        case 1:
            printf("\t\t\t1. PLAY\n");
            printf("\t\t\t2. INSTRUCTIONS\n");
            printf("\t\t\t3. STATISTICS\n");
            printf("\t\t\t4. EXIT\n\n");

            printf("\t\t\tENTER A NUMBER (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &def);

            if (def == 1) {
                void displayBoard();
            }

            if (def == 2) {
                printf("----INSTRUCTIONS----\n\n");

                printf("To begin the game, select play in the menu.\n");
                printf("This is your board:\n\n");
                printf("----------\n");
                printf("1 | 2 | 3\n");
                printf("----------\n");
                printf("4 | 5 | 6\n");
                printf("----------\n");
                printf("7 | 8 | 9\n");
                printf("----------\n\n");
                printf("Players will take turns inputting their X or O, ('X' or 'O') by entering the number on the board.\n");
                printf("The first player to get three of their letter in a row wins.\n\n");
            }

            if (def == 3) {
                struct Player;
            }

            if (def == 4) {
                fclose;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

            do {
                displayBoard();
                player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

                printf("Player %d, enter a number:  ", player);
                scanf("%d", &choice);

                mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

                if (choice == 1 && square[1] == '1') {
                    square[1] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 2 && square[2] == '2') {
                    square[2] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 3 && square[3] == '3') {
                    square[3] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 4 && square[4] == '4') {
                    square[4] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 5 && square[5] == '5') {
                    square[5] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 6 && square[6] == '6') {
                    square[6] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 7 && square[7] == '7') {
                    square[7] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 8 && square[8] == '8') {
                    square[8] = mark;
                } else if (choice == 9 && square[9] == '9') {
                    square[9] = mark;
                } else {
                    printf("Invalid move ");
                    player--;
                    getch();
                }
                i = checkWin();

                player++;
            } while (i == -1);
            {
                displayBoard();
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                printf("==>\aPlayer %d win ", --player);
            } else {
                printf("==>\aGame draw");
            }

            getch();
            int selection();
    }
}
```

Switch statement isn't printing, I have tried moving code around, putting it inside of its own function, everything. I've defaulted to putting it inside of main to hopefully allow it to print but instead it defaults to printing the tic tac toe board and skips the switch statement completely.

Comment: Code is unfinished as well, so any errors are being fixed atm :)

Comment: The default value of a global variable `choices` without explicit initial value is `0`, so `case 1` is not ececuted. There are no other cases, so nothing is executed.

Comment: I think (hope) you also did not intend to have both a variable `choices` and one called `choice`.

Comment: `choices` is going to be changed. I figured it out! Thanks for the help Mike. It took someones wording to fix it for me.

Comment: @newah: save time.  Enable all warnings: `warning: implicit declaration of function 'getch' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]        getch();`, `error: 'fclose' undeclared (first use in this function)   fclose;`, .... others

Comment: OT: In `checkWin()`, there's no need for all those `else` branches... `return` is going to change the flow of execution when any `if()` proves to be `true`...

Comment: Also @Fe2O3, if they're all going to return `1`, those could all be `||`ed together.

Answer (score 0):

From [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75569483/switch-statement-inside-of-main-but-is-not-outputting-and-instead-skipping-stra#comment133325378_75569483):

> The default value of a global variable `choices` without explicit initial value is `0`, so `case 1` is not executed. There are no other cases, so nothing is executed.

–
[MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4062354/mikecat)